# Enabling gzip compression for network solution eCommerce website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Hello i am using network solutions eCommerce package 
my website is http://www.shahji.com/
I just want to speed up my website 
and also want give expiration to my images but i don't know how 
can you please help me with details

Answer (score 1):

You can enable GZIP with your .htaccess file. See for an example the HTML5 Boilerplate file. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess This is a perfectly fine method to achieve this.

However, it would be even better if you enable these server settings in your webserver settings, not just in your website directory through .htaccess. This prevents another HTTP request when downloading your website.

Answer (score 0):

For better speed of you website, it's good practice to gzip your website, as while a website response to browser with gzip, it sent site data in compressed format to browser, like if your website size is 200kb, after compression it will be sent 10kb to browser which will definitely boost your website speed performance, as then browser uncompressed that and show it to visitors.